# Conditional CDF of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Here is the question:

> The lifetime $X$ of a machine has a continuous CDF. Find the conditional CDF and PDF given the event $C = \{X \gt t\} $.

Solution:
$$F_X(x|X\gt t) = \mathbb{P}[X\le x| X\gt t] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[\{X\le x\} \cap \{X\gt t\}]}{\mathbb{P}[X\gt t]}$$

So we have:

$$ F_X(x|X\gt t) = \frac{F_X(x) - F_X(t)}{1 - F_X(t)} , \ x\gt t$$

According to my book, the PDF is given by:
$$ f_X(x|X\gt t) = \frac{f_X(x)}{1 - F_X(t)} , \ x\ge t$$

The problem is $x=t$. Why $x=t$ is included in PDF? We should differentiate CDF with respect to $x$ and so $x=t$ shouldn't be included.

Comment: I do agree, that from an intuitive perspective, $x>t$ makes better sense, but since PDF's are only uniquely determined up to null sets, changing the PDF at a single point will not change the probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Density functions are not unique; they are only unique up to a set of measure $0$. Changing the value of  a density function at a point makes no difference.